# Esp8266 & Nodemcu: Method returning an request string

Tags: c++, string, esp8266, nodemcu

For the love of god, I am not able to build a simple Method which iterates through every scanned network and concatenates a String out of the BSSID and its Strength. Im feeling like super dump.

I need this pattern:

```
http://IP:PORT/localize?mac1=x.x.x.x&strength1=-30&mac2=x.x.x.x&strength2=-40...
```

This is what I got so far:

```
const char* build_request(){
  int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();

  char urlout[512];
  strcpy(urlout, host);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    char buffer[8];
    strcat(urlout, "&mac");
    sprintf(buffer, "%d", i);
    strcat(urlout, buffer);
    strcat(urlout, "=");
    strcat(urlout, WiFi.BSSIDstr(i).c_str());
    strcat(urlout, "&strength");
    strcat(urlout, buffer);
    strcat(urlout, "=");
    //strcat(urlout, WiFi.RSSI(i)); 
  }

  return urlout;
```

Apart of the fact the output contains sometimes weird signs like this:

```
http://IP:5000/localize&mac0=44:4E:6D:53:88:C1&strength0=&mac1=90:5C:44:C5:C6:B7&strength1=&mac2=38:10:D5:B2:64:10&strength2=&mac3=34:2C:C4:B7:72:D6&strength3=&mac4=00:15:0C:E1:CB:␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␟␀␀␀=K␐@␌␅␀@4:34:6B:EF:7�^ @0␀␀␀␘␀␀␀����␌_ @␜␀␀`␜␀␀`U␁␀␀�8 @␀␀�␀␀␀␀�=␀�?P␂␀␀���?␂␀␀␀␀␀␀␀=␀␀␀~␀␀␀U␁␀␀0␀␀␀h7=&mac8=EA:DF:70:FA:D8:A3&strength8=
```

Also

```
strcat(urlout, WiFi.RSSI(i));
```

says:

```
argument of type "int32_t" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"
```

although for example a `Serial.print()` which also expects a const char* is able to print the RSSI Value..

Can someone lead me in the right direction for properly building a string out of vars and avoiding buffer overflows, etc ...

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urlout` is a *local* variable, and as such its life-time ends when it goes out of scope (when your function returns), leaving you with an invalid pointer.

I recommend that you pass the array as an argument to the function instead:

```
const char* build_request(char *urlout){ ... }
```

Optionally, and if your target and compiler support it, use C++ `std::string` instead.